# EmberJS Handling DOM Events using Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, view, ember.js

I want to toggle a single form (see picture below) using views.
My code basically works when i add new formset it adds an empty bracket to json and then i 
print the json out using eachloop

View template

```
{{#each view.anotherField}}

<div class="panel panel-default">
     {{action 'toggleView' 'toggleViews' target='view'}}
        ...
</div>       
{{#unless view.toggleViews}}
...content to toggle...
{{/unless}}
```

View  controller??

```
actions: {
    showMoreFields: function(){
      this.get('anotherField').pushObject({name: ''});
```

,

```
toggleView: function(param){
      this.toggleProperty(param);
    }
```

[image]

In this given picture u can see ive toggled organization view to truth what i would like is to toggle only the clicked part not all of the forms. Is there a solution ?

Cheers,

Kristjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to handle events for specific parts/forms of your view. To achieve this there are at least three approaches,

**1**.Use the `{{action}}` helper passing the object you want to modify. Then in your function modify a property of that object and reflect that in your template e.g. toggle the form. Maybe in your case it could be something like ,

```
....
{{#each field in view.anotherField}}

<div class="panel panel-default">
     {{action 'toggleView' field target='view'}}
....
```

**2**.Make a sub view/template (e.g. SubFormView) to accomodate each of your forms and handle the event of toggle within this view. Then include this via the `{{view}}` helper within the template of your main view.

**3**.Use pure js DOM handling (no {{action}} helper) and call your ember components from there.

Example of approaches 1 and 3 can be found here,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/acUCocu/1

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <i>using <b>&#123;&#123;action&#125;&#125;</b> helper</i>
    <ul>
    {{#each color in model}}
      <li {{action 'test' color}}>{{color.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <i>using pure js DOM event handling</i>
    <ul>
    {{#each color in model}}
      <li onclick="Ember.View.views[$(this).closest('.ember-view').attr('id')].controller.send('test2',this)">{{color.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return colors;
  },
  actions:{
    test:function(param){
      alert('this is color:'+param.get('name')+" ("+param+")");
    },
    test2:function(elem){
      alert('from pure js, clicked element: '+elem);
      $(elem).css('color','red');
    }
  }
});

App.Color = Ember.Object.extend({
  name:null
});

var colors=[];
colors.pushObject(App.Color.create({name:'red'}));
colors.pushObject(App.Color.create({name:'green'}));
colors.pushObject(App.Color.create({name:'blue'}));
```

Comment: @kristjan thanks,  i'm glad it worked. Happy new year!

Comment: Melc, ive seen you given many very useful answers, i wonder if i could  ask your help with hasMany relation ? I wud make jsbin n so on .

Comment: @kristjanreinhold thanks, but can you please create a new thread with your question and I as well as many others will assist you.